# Error when trying to set up db from command line "rake aborted"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql, ubuntu, activerecord

I've been trying to set up a test db, but when trying to create, I keep coming across an error that I can't seem to get past when trying to populate the db.

When I execute:

```
bundle exec rake db:create db:migrate db:test:prepare --trace
```

create and migrate seem to run without errors when run separately, but test:prepare seems to throw the error.

The error starts with:

```
** Invoke db:test:prepare (first_time)
** Invoke db:abort_if_pending_migrations (first_time)
** Invoke environment (first_time)
** Execute environment
** Invoke db:load_config (first_time)
** Execute db:load_config
** Execute db:abort_if_pending_migrations
** Invoke environment
** Execute db:test:prepare
** Invoke db:test:load (first_time)
** Invoke db:test:purge (first_time)
** Invoke environment
** Invoke db:load_config
** Execute db:test:purge
** Execute db:test:load
** Invoke db:test:load_schema (first_time)
** Invoke db:test:purge
** Execute db:test:load_schema
** Invoke db:schema:load (first_time)
** Invoke environment
** Invoke db:load_config
** Execute db:schema:load
rake aborted!
ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: PG::UndefinedTable: ERROR:  relation "capabilities" does not exist
LINE 5:
```

I've looked up, and tried a lot of the results shown on google, but none seem to help. New to this, so I'm completely stumped at this stage.

UPDATE:
I should mention that when doing:

```
rake db:create RAILS_ENV=test
->payments_test already exists
rake db:migrate RAILS_ENV=test
->rake aborted!
NoMethodError: undefined method `mq' for #<Rails::Application::Configuration:0x0000000508acf0> blah blah blah
```

Comment: It looks like your test db is not set. Maybe try this:
```rake db:create RAILS_ENV=test``` and see if prepare runs?

Comment: @KrzysztofWitczak I've tried this earlier as well, output being: 

payments_test already exists

Comment: try `rake db:reset RAILS_ENV=test`

Comment: @AaronBreckenridge Getting the same error as in my update again.

Comment: Looks like your application is misconfigured. Where are you calling `.mq`?